# Visual Studio plugin to convert loops to parallel loops

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development, visual-studio

I am trying to make my application faster. Besides optimizing the algorithms, introducing caches etc. I'd like to better scale with hardware, i.e. make use of multiple CPUs/cores or hyperthreading.

So I find myself converting simple loops into parallel loops (`Parallel.For()` / `Parallel.ForEach()`) and I wonder whether there's a Visual Studio plugin that would automate this task.

The plugin

- should be gratis
- must work with `for` and `foreach` loops
- must work in Visual Studio 2015 (Visual Studio 2013 would be nice as well)
- needn't find out by itself whether the loop body causes threading issues. That's something I'll do myself.
- may depend on JetBrains ReSharper (8.2 or higher)
- must not use external libraries for parallelism (like GPU libraries or Intel Parallel library)

Comment: I'm not sure you should do this as a blanket change. A loop being "parallizable" depends on a lot of things and just blindly changing them can cause potentially large bugs. I'd also say that in some cases, using a parallel loop can actually make things slower, not faster. That being said, you could write a Fody plugin that does this, but I don't think there is anything out there that does it since it really isn't as easy as "change every loop".

Comment: Sure. I'am using a profiler before and I'm checking the loops manually for threading issues.